# Reshaping an image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, image-masking

I was searching for an online tool or tutorial to reshape an image. What i exactly want is something like this.

[image: image 1]

So that i can reshape it into something like this

[image: image 2]

I found this functionality in [this website!](http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/app).. But i couldn't trace how they did it. I've googled for hours but ended up with some broken urls. I'm not a designer to start with but i have to do this. Someone please tell me how to do this..

Comment: you are not in the right place for asking about design, try on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ , anyway if you want to turn your flat image to a vector you can use illustrator,inkscape, or some vectorial tool for designers

Comment: Mhm... this can't be more magic than a path kind of data structure drawn on a html5 canvas but you need an exact explaination how to do this on the canvas right?

Comment: @Chris Yup.. Please give me a start

Answer (score 1):

You can have a closer look to html5 canvas tutorials like [THIS.](http://www.onlywebpro.com/2011/06/25/html5-canvas-for-absolute-beginners-part-1/)

In this tutorial for example "Part 2: Drawing Shape With Paths" will be interesting for you. To have those "handles" you will need to draw some simple rectangles at every point in your path.

Everything more about this would go too much in detail. I think this is a good place to start for you.